# Spring CrudRepository .orElseThrow()

Tags: java, spring, java-8, crud, spring-boot

What is the proper way to throw an exception if a database query returns empty? I'm trying to use the `.orElseThrow()` method but it won't compile :

```
Meeting meeting = meetingRepository.findByMeetingId(meetingId).orElseThrow(new MeetingDoesNotExistException(meetingId));
```

The compiler is saying :

> "he method orElseThrow(Supplier) in the type Optional is not applicable for the arguments (MeetingRestController.MeetingDoesNotExistException)

Is it possible to do this with lambda expressions?

CrudRepository :

```
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface MeetingRepository extends CrudRepository<Meeting, Long>{
    Optional<Meeting> findByMeetingId(Long id);
}
```

Exception :

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT) // 409
class MeetingDoesNotExistException extends RuntimeException{
  public MeetingDoesNotExistException(long meetingId){
    super("Meeting " + meetingId + " does not exist.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try passing a lambda expression of type `Supplier<MeetingDoesNotExistException>` :

```
Meeting meeting = 
    meetingRepository.findByMeetingId(meetingId)
                     .orElseThrow(() -> new MeetingDoesNotExistException(meetingId));
```

Comment: @Eran can you explain this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180844/spring-data-jpa-restcontroller-repository-optional-strange-behavior

Answer (score 3):

The error means what it says.

The documentation for [`orElseThrow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) states that it takes a `Supplier` as a parameter.

You have stated your exception is a `RuntimeException`, which is not a `Supplier`. Therefore, `orElseThrow()` is not applicable to that argument type. You would have to pass it a `Supplier`, not a `RuntimeException`.

It would be simpler syntax to use a lambda expression.