# spring-data-jpa @RestController @Repository Optional strange behavior

Tags: java, spring-boot, option-type, spring-restcontroller, spring-repositories

My @RestController

```java
@GetMapping("/projects/{project_id}")
public Project getProjectById(@PathVariable(value = "project_id") UUID projectId) {
    return projectRepository.findById(projectId).orElseThrow(Util.notFound(projectId));
}
```

My projectRepository is

```java
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Project, UUID> {
}
```

```java
public class Util {

    static Supplier<ResourceNotFoundException> notFound(UUID msg) {
        log.error(msg + " not found");
        return () -> new ResourceNotFoundException(msg + " not found");
    }
}
```

When i do GET `{{host}}/projects/{{projId1}}`, it return the result. However, in the log, it show .

```
org.hibernate.SQL: select project0_.id as id1_4_0_, proje...  
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [OTHER]  
ERROR: projectId not found .
```

How is it orElseThrow always got executed, after the data has been returned?

Comment: I think we will need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible in order to reproduce this. Do you have a git repo or any similar.

Comment: Just a side note: The `@Repository` annotation is redundant on `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

Comment: @earthw0rmjim yes you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix your `Util`

```
public class Util {
    static Supplier<ResourceNotFoundException> notFound(UUID msg) {
        return () -> {
            log.error(msg + " not found");
            return new ResourceNotFoundException(msg + " not found");
        };
    }
}
```

You need to log only in case you actually throw it.

Comment: I'm still not clear....If whatever inside `.orElseThrow(Supplier s)` is lazily evaluated, then the `log.error()` statement should not be executed right? The fact that I see the log statement in the log indicates that the body of the `Supplier` got executed?

Comment: Why do you think that "whatever inside `.orElseThrow(Supplier s)` is lazily evaluated"? `Supplier` method `get` called on demand, but `Supplier` instance is created eager.